# How can we take the filename from user while using content-disposition:attachment

Tags: java, angularjs, download, content-disposition

On click of button, I need the contents of api to be downloaded. I'm using content-disposition:attachment to achieve it. But it's using the default name for the downloaded file. I need the name of the file to be given by the user for saving in local system.

Currently the contents are getting downloaded and saved by file name (downloadedFileName) set in the response header.

In server side code

```
final String contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadedFileName + "\"";
response.header("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
```

Comment: What is the type of response object here? If it is HttpServletResponse type, shouldn't you use setHeader method? Also, please post the the http response headers that were returned to the browser.

Comment: The header is set using response.header where 'response' is of type Response.ResponseBuilder. The content-disposition:attachment header is getting set in the response and the file is getting downloaded.My problem is I want the filename to be given by the user when the button is clicked

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code that you are using for the download action?